# Calling a method that returns a URL in groovy script

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovy-console

```
def publishVersion() {
    def Payload = versionPayload()
    def response = httpRequest(
        customHeaders: [
            [ name: "Authorization", value: "Bearer " + env.BEARER_TOKEN ],
            [ name: "Content-Type", value: "application/vnd.api+json" ]
        ],
        httpMode: 'POST',
        requestBody: "${Payload}",
        url: "https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/organizations/my-organization/registry-modules/private/my-organization/vnet/provider/versions"
    )
    def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.content)
    println ("Run Id: " + data.data.links.upload)
    return data.data.links.upload
}
def UPLOAD
UPLOAD = sh(
        '''curl \
        --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
        --request PUT \
        --data-binary @module.tar.gz \
        data.data.links.upload 
        '''
)
```

I am trying to create a module version in Terraform cloud. The `publishVersion()` method will invoke the API call and part of the API response is a URL where the module will be uploaded. And  that URL is what `publishVersion()` is returning as `data.data.links.upload`. The URL returned by the `publishVersion()` method, I am trying to upload the `module.tar.gz`  to the URL by using the UPLOAD method in the last part. "it says could not resolve host."

Comment: What's failing? What errors do you get?

Comment: it says could not resolve host.

Comment: The URL returned by the publishVersion() method, I am trying to upload the module.tar.gz  to the URL by using the UPLOAD method in the last part. "it says could not resolve host. "

Comment: I don't see where you are calling the publishVersion function.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to do something like the below.

```
def URL = publishVersion()
UPLOAD = sh(
        """curl \
        --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
        --request PUT \
        --data-binary @module.tar.gz \
        ${URL}
        """
)
```